# dpkg pip-installs wheels as 'root' user

Tags: root, deb, pip

I've created a DEB package containing a bunch of Python wheels which the `postinst` script pip installs. The problem is that because the DEB file apparently has to be run as sudo, e.g. `dpkg -i acme-gizmo_1.2.2_x86-64.deb`, I get lots of warnings about running pip as a root user, i.e.

> WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

I don't see any use in using a virtual environment because the package and wheels are not intended for a virtual environment. This is a customer install.

Is there a way to install a DEB package locally, without super-user privileges.